# puppeteer nodejs instagram problem after 4-5 times

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I have some problems with puppeteer.

I call the site instagram with a username. It works. But after 5-6 times instagram says to login.

So how I handle this ? I log to instagram then I go to the userpage and crawl the description text.

Now its like this: it works but only 4-5 times then I have to login:

```
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");

const verification = async username => {
    try {
        const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: false, ignoreHTTPSErrors: true});
        const page = await browser.newPage();
        page.setUserAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/72.0.3626.121 Safari/537.36");

        await page.goto(`https://www.instagram.de/${username}`, {waitUntil: 'networkidle2', timeout: 0, ignoreHTTPSErrors: true});
        const d = await page.waitForSelector(".-vDIg > span"); // get Desc
        const value = await d.evaluate(el => el.textContent);

        await browser.close();
        console.log(value);
        console.log("-- bingo --");

    } catch (e) {
        console.log("our error", e);
    }
};

module.exports = verification;
```

Anyone has a solution for this problem ? I need your help

Comment: You can save your credentials and detect the login screen puppeteer also can save the cookies and the session.

Comment: What I usually do instead is to use puppeteer core and use connect to attach to the current chrome that way you can use your save credentials from the actual browser you are using or setup profile with shortcut to be used.

Comment: @RicardoSilva I thank you for your answers. But I have no idea how I setup the profile with a shortcut. Do you have any examples maybe for me ?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry it took so long to reply.

I don't know how much you know from puppeteer core.
But the code below will grab the tab that matches the url you put in, hence preserving any session/cookie/auth you have manually done.

```
/* eslint-disable import/extensions */ /* eslint-disable no-underscore-dangle */
/* eslint-disable-next-line import/no-extraneous-dependencies */
import puppeteer from 'puppeteer-core';
/* eslint-disable-next-line import/no-extraneous-dependencies */
import fetch from 'node-fetch';

const browserRemoteDebuggerUrl = 'you name it';

const pup = (async () => {
  const debugJson = await (await fetch(new URL(browserRemoteDebuggerUrl))).json();
  const browser = await puppeteer.connect({
    browserWSEndpoint: debugJson.webSocketDebuggerUrl,
    defaultViewport: null,
  });
  const _pages = await browser.pages(); let page = {};
  try {
    // eslint-disable-next-line prefer-destructuring
    page = _pages.filter(x => x.url())[0];
    return {
      page,
      browser,
    };
  } catch (e) {
    browser.disconnect(); return console.log('page not found?');
  }
})();

export async function evaluate() {
  const puppeteer_ = await pup;
  try {
    await puppeteer_.page.evaluate(stuff);
    await puppeteer_.browser.disconnect();
  } catch (error) {
    // eslint-disable-next-line
    console.error('page not found?\n', error);
    await puppeteer_.browser.disconnect();
  }
}

export default pup;
```

you can still use the same logic to spawn a new browser from a local path, meaning that you can pass the profile you want to open as argument to the chrome executable. I used to that but I do not have that code anymore.

EDIT: you need remote debugging on in chrome, also you don't want to have devtools console opened before you reach the "page.evaluate" part this usually causes bugs for me. What I usually do is place a break point on that line, then open the devtools, then resume on node.